# Relation between Akka and Flink TaskManager

Tags: akka, apache-flink

I'm a newbie to Flink.

I just installed Flink on my local PC and submitted a Flink job. In the Flink web UI `TaskManagers` menu, I can see that the `path, id` is "akka://flink/user/taskmanager"

I want to know what this means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship between Akka and Flink is that Flink implements a few internal components as Akka actors: `JobManager`, `TaskManager`, and `JobClient`. More information is detailed in the [Flink documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Akka+and+Actors).

The string `akka://flink/user/taskmanager` is an [actor path](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/general/addressing.html#what-is-an-actor-path-), which indicates where an actor resides in the actor supervision hierarchy: `flink` is the name of the actor system, and `user` is the guardian actor for all user-created top-level actors. The `TaskManager` actor is directly beneath the guardian actor, which means that `TaskManager` is a top-level actor that is created via the `ActorSystem.actorOf` method.